# Is there a way to convert a System.Data.DataTable to a Spark DataFrame?

Tags: c#, apache-spark

I have an `Excel.Workbook` object that I convert into a `System.Data.DataTable`. I would like to convert this into a `DataFrame` provided by Microsoft.

If there is a way to go from `Excel.Workbook` to `DataFrame` that would be awesome.

I went through the documentation and can't seem to find what I am looking for. There is a project called RDotNet that seems promising but it's not maintained.

Comment: Do you mean a .NET dataframe or a Spark dataframe?